# Changing a integer into a string Python 3

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to write out a program that tells how much damage someone causes to an object and i want to also print out how much damage it delt, but even after looking what I found doesn't seem to work. Here is the code

```
damage = random.randint(1,3)
print ("You delt %"+damage+"% damage")
```

If any one knows why it isn't working I would be very thankful.

Comment: What are the {} doing there?

Comment: I am very bad at using this website... But I'm learning

Comment: @cryce, you cannot add a string and an int, use `print("You delt {}% damage".format(damage))`

Comment: Fixed that for you. Please always include the full error message. "Something does not work" is not helpful. Although in this case, it is obvious that you'll have to use `str(damage)` in your call to `print`.

Answer (score 2):

```
print ("You delt %" + str(damage) + "% damage")
You delt %1% damage
```

better way:

```
print ("You delt %{}% damage".format(damage))
```

Comment: What's with the `%`?

Comment: Ah, thank you, it works perfectly now

Comment: I had found another supposed way to print integers as strings but it seems I misunderstood

Comment: @e0k, just using the question's text.

Comment: @cryce, you means `print ("You delt %d damage" % damage)` ?